# DateTime conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm totally new to rails (and, of corse, to ruby).

Rails by default, when you create a table, adds a "created_at" column.

The created_at column display something like this 2012-05-08 17:23:58 UTC.

How can I display the same date in another format? Something like this: 08/05/2012 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [DateTime#strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) for this.

```
obj.created_at
 => Thu, 22 Mar 2012 00:07:12 UTC +00:00

obj.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
 => "03/22/2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

From  [DateTime#Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html)

obj.created_at.to_default_s
    => "2012-05-08"

Something like this: "08/05/2012"